# JQuery: Loading content into dynamic tabs with load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a main menu, where if I click on any of the options a tab is dynamically created in a div. So I can create up to nine tabs of different options out there in the main menu.
The javascript code I use to create and delete tabs is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#tabs").tabs();
            var tabCounter = 1;
            var cont =1;

            var num_tabs = $("#tabs ul li").length +1,
            tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
            tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

        // actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
        function addTab() {
            var label = tabTitle || "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
            tabContentHtml = "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";
            tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
            tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'></div>" );
            tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            cont++;

        }

         // close icon: removing the tab on click
        tabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
            var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
            $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
            tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            cont--;
        });

        tabs.bind( "keyup", function( event ) {
            if ( event.altKey && event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.BACKSPACE ) {
                var panelId = tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-active" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
                $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
                tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            }
        });



       $(".menuitem a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

      if(cont<=9)
      { 
        tabTitle = $(this).attr("title"),
        addTab();
        $("#tabs-"+tabCounter).load($(this).attr('href'));

        tabCounter++;
        $("#tabs").tabs({active: $('.ui-tabs-nav li:last').index()});
      }
      else
      {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });    
      }
});    

});
```

I wanted to get it by adding a tab is activated and show your content, so I added:

```
   $("#tabs").tabs({active: $('.ui-tabs-nav li:last').index()});
```

Until there all right, I could show up to 9 tabs, but missing your content, it would be a path Symfony,for example:

```
 <li class ="menuitem"><a href="{{path('index')}}">test</a></li>
```

Then I added the following code to load this route into the div:

```
$("#tabs-"+tabCounter).load($(this).attr('href'));
```

And the result is that the content for each tab appears, but it only appears automatically activates the first tab does not show me the warning dialog that can not display more than 9 tabs. The code above is something that affects others and I can not get a solution to this problem.

Besides this problem, I need to know how to get that pressing an option from the main menu, if there is an open tab with that content to put the active tab and display its contents, instead of opening another like (there can be two tabs of the same content).

If there is a better way to do this, I would like to know.

I'm a newbie, so I apologize for how to explain it.

Comment: Can u create a http://jsfiddle.net/ with ur code?

Comment: Here's what you ask, but the content of the tabs is a simple text, because as I can not add the full symfony project can not include the path to display the corresponding twig template in the content of the tab. In this case if the last tab created as can be tested in the example is activated, but when I include the path with the load () method and fails to do this and is active initially only the first tab is created, the other must be Press it to see its content and make it active. http://jsfiddle.net/JMMS_85/o7610t24/

Comment: If no other way to do this, I'd like to know and try. I read somewhere that AJAX could do that, but I do not know how.